# Page linking in the admin suite

Tags: wordpress

I'm *trying* to develop a wordpress plugin but have become unstuck very quickly.

The plugin within the admin is to act as a way for users to set up various database fields so that the front end of the wordpress site can then use these. This is going to happen over several pages, one for each task. 
I'd want to be able to load these pages in from links on a main page.

This I can do but these pages do not load into the wordpress admin site they just load on there own.

How can I load these pages in (using hook calls?) to the wordpress admin site, right of the menu?

I have got my plugin to appear in the menu with add_object_page and have called that using add_action. I have a page loading up fine but cannot link to any other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was very tired yesterday and failed to try using the slug.

The slug you give to menu items to fire off a function can be used again on other links. The slug will do the same as it does on the menu items!